# whether to use job scheduler or sleep() function

Tags: cron, sleep

I am confused whether to use cron job scheduler or use sleep function in the program itself. There are questions on this previously but I seem to have some different requirements form them.

I need some information from the previous run of the program so if I use cron to schedule 
job I would have to store that information at some place and re-read it next time(this can make the program less scale-able if the size of this information grows).
I can also use sleep() but that will be using resources.

I will need to re-run the program every 10 mins or so. Which one is better to use. 
Is there any other nice way of doing it which I may be missing.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should use cron whenever you can for something like this.

The only problem I could foresee is if your program somehow took longer than 10 minutes to run, cron is going to call the next execution 10 minutes later anyway. This creates a really long race condition basically, where if you did sleep it would only start sleeping after the previous execution ended.

But assuming your program will take less time to run, I say go with cron.

Comment: we can add conditions to corn to execute a schedule only when previous one has finisheed.

Comment: true, so really it just depends on the amount of information you want to load in RAM and keep there. your main concern seems to lie with performance so we would need a lot more details about the system (specs, what else is running, how long do you plan on running this) to give you a good performance estimate

Comment: I am in a similar situation and the cron solution seems a bit more resilient to me. Am I wrong?